# What does "late" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, lyrics

What does late mean in this sentence?

> Late in the winter of my seventeenth year...

Comment: Late: (happening or being) near the end of a period of time. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/late Winter is a period of time, near the end of that specific winter.

Comment: @RubioRic I posted this question because I wanted more explanation about the word "late". I didn't find the explanation in Cambridge dictionary, comprehensive enough. So I posted this question to get more details about this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the meanings of "late" is "towards the end of a period". The period can be an amount of time, such as a day, a week, a month, a year, etc, or a season. Late in the winter means when winter is almost over, when it is nearly spring.

[Late *Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/late)

Comment: Both answers are correct, but the original answer is stated in a needlessly complicated manner so I voted for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Late is opposite of early: Early in the morning, late in the evening.

Early in the winter: end of December. Late in the winter: beginning of March.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean!

Comment: Late in the winter is: in the end of the cold season, in the end of ramadan.

Comment: That was his seventeenth year, i.e. he was sixteen years old at that time. It was wintertime. But it was *late* wintertime, as Albrecht says, it was probably the end of February or the first week of March.

Comment: Doesn't Ramadan vary among the seasons?

Comment: Ramadan in the UK this year starts on 5 May, when winter has been over for a long time.

Comment: You know, we are being Northern-Hemisphere-centric here, aren't we?

Comment: Yes, this must be very late in the winter, almost in the middle of spring.